# jquery MOBILE issue -> using .removeClass and .addClass not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

Couldn't find anyone having the same issue (search results usually return ridiculous coding errors with jquery and css, but that's not the case here.

Problem:
I have

with classes 'active', and 'inactive'.

On inactive - the list item will have a background image 1
on active - hte list item will have background image 2

```html
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a></a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

On click, it's supposed to switch them right... example code:

```js
$('ul li.inactive>a').live('click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        theLI = $(this).closest("li");
            // active / deactivate buttons
            theLI.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');   
    });
```

With JQUERY MOBILE this code doesn't work, I've tried adding the class first, then removing... also tried toggleclass for the active.

If I removing jquery mobile from being included, it works perfectly.
Add jquery mobile library back in, doesn't work.

Not a css problem.

Upon inspection with firebug, it seems removing classes works find, it's when it tries to add it?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.inactive {color:red;}
.active {color:blue;}
</style>

<script>
    $('ul li.inactive>a').live('click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        theLI = $(this).closest("li");
            // active / deactivate buttons
            theLI.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');   
    });
    $('ul li.active>a').live('click', function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        theLI = $(this).closest("li");
            // active / deactivate buttons
            theLI.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');   
    });
</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>index.html</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
           <ul>
               <li class="active"><a>One</a></li>
               <li class="inactive"><a>Two</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```